# ReactJS ViewPort Meta being ignored

Tags: html, reactjs

I am working on a ReactJS project (create-react-app) and in my public folder I have the HTML file which contains

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

I tried both

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.5" />
```

and

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2, maximum-scale=1.5" />
```

but these changes appeared to not do anything from  both `npm run start` and `npm run build >  serve -s build`. I checked the HTML file in the build folder and the `meta` tags had correctly updated.

Does anyone have a clue why this might not be affecting my screen? I am on a laptop and have tried Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Have to tried `initial-scale=1.0`

Comment: Yes I have tried this, and I tried 2 decimal points also.

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: The user is able to zoom and the initial zoom is whatever zoom was last used.