# ReactJS, How to keep viewport initial-scale=1.0 when build in create react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, meta-tags

I am working on a ReactJS project (create-react-app) and in my public folder I have the HTML file which contains

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This one always change to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

when I build it. But I need to keep initial-scale=1.0 not 1.
Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: 1.0 and 1 both means same

Comment: Hi @angelo, I don't know why.
But when I used 1 the meta viewport does not work.
Then I used 1.0 that worked.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248740/reactjs-viewport-meta-being-ignored

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is issue with html minification. This should be webpack setting in create-react-app.

In order to turn it off you can reject CRA or use https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired

Here you can find more details in this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165466/how-to-build-a-production-version-of-react-without-minification)